Cannot access UEFI, GRUB or boot into OS while SSD is in laptop
As the title suggests, I cannot access anything at all while my SSD is plugged in my laptop after shutting it down yesterday. I've tried spamming UEFI access key (F2) or BOOT menu key (F12) as fast as possible as soon as I power on my laptop but nothing changes, it always just gets stuck on ACER logo. However, once I unplug my SSD I can easily access UEFI menu with F2 and even boot into Fedora live USB.
I've tried CMOS reset and have fast/secure boot disabled, but it didn't help. My suspicion is that GRUB got somehow corrupted so I tried to rebuild it with live USB, but I cannot boot it while SSD is in.
Laptop is ACER Nitro 5 AN517-42R71F, and is Fedora/Win 11 dual boot. Any help to at least get Live USB booted would be appreciated.

Try and use the Advanced Startup option within Settings

I cannot boot into Windows at all, and I'm not using Windows boot manager to access it with 3 forced restarts. I could access it with windows live usb if I removed my SSD, but then I can't fix my EFI partition

Your drive likely failed to a point it freezes POST. Replace it. It has nothing to do with GRUB or any installed OS,. Accessing the firmware settings happens before GRUB or any other bootloader is even called. That it is corrupt is almost a given but because everything else is.

You seem to disagree with yourself: "I can easily access UEFI menu with F2 and even boot into Fedora live USB." vs. "Any help to at least get Live USB booted would be appreciated." You have already found the answer -- remove SSD. If you want to test the SSD, or try to salvage data, put in an external USB box, and plug it in after booting.

Ok, thanks everyone, I'll try to save it with external USB box tomorrow, when stores open so I can buy it.

My SSD was fried. Replacing it fixed the issue and I installed OS on new SSD with no problems.

Upon power on, all machines do a POST [Power On Self-Test] to ensure the hardware itself is fine to power up. I'm unsure at what point peripherals are also tested, however whatever the electrical issue was with the SSD, it was detected and the firmware prevented the machine from booting so as to not allow any new damage to occur to the peripheral and other hardware
